# How to get from Moustieres-Sainte-Marie, France to Juan-Les-Pins, France by public transport?

Tags: france, buses

I am a pensioner and need to get from Moustieres-Sainte-Marie to Juan-Les-Pins. I am thinking:

bus 27 from Moustieres to Castellane,
bus 31 from Castellane to Grasse then
train from Grasse to Juan-Les-Pins.

There is a problem, in that the only bus from Moustieres is 11.20am and arrives in Castellane after the first bus leaves for Grasse at 10.55am, the next being 19.05.

Has anyone out there any alternative suggestions please?

Comment: Hi and welcome. I am afraid this question might be off-topic here on TSE since [we really  don't do travel scheduling](http://travel.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) as per our rules.

Comment: Try the other way around: go by Aix en Provence or Marseille. (leave Moustier at 13:50 by bus 27, stop at Aix at 15.40). Then go to Le Cannet by line 20 (leave aix at 18:00, stop at le cannet at 19.45). ven faster: stop at Marseille Saint Charles at  16h15 and take a train to .. Juan les pins !